# What does // and //= mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

This is the part of the code:

```
 return undef if ($mate{$grid_edge->[0]} // '') eq $grid_edge->[1];

$node->{count} //= count($node->{low}) + count($node->{high});
```

So What does `// ''` and `//=` mean in Perl in the above lines of code?

Comment: Like all Perl operators, this is explained in `perldoc perlop`, also [available here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). Search for "C-style Logical Defined-Or" (if you search for "//", you'll need to skip over a lot of uses of `//` in pattern matching).

Answer (score 6):

The `//` operator is officially the [Logical Defined-Or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) operator.

In the first line:

```
($mate{$grid_edge->[0]} // '')
```

means: if `$mate{$grid_edge->[0]}` is defined, use that value, else use `''` as the value. Note that the single quotes are simply an empty string, not a part of the operator.

In the second line:

```
$node->{count} //= count($node->{low}) + count($node->{high});
```

If `$node->{count}` is not defined, assign it `count($node->{low}) + count($node->{high})`.